# POST https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token 415 Unsupported Media when using fetch

Tags: javascript, json, http

I'm trying to make a request to get an authorization code from the spotify api using fetch but I keep getting a 415 error code.

```
class CodeHandler {
  constructor(Args){
    this._args = Args;
    this.opts = {
       data: {
         name: "test",
         public: "false",
     grant_type: 'authorization_code',
     code: this._args[1],
     redirect_uri: 'http%3A%2F%2Ftest.openjukeboxdev.info%2F'
       },
       headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Basic ZjRmMTk0MTIzOTM3NDgyMmI5Mjg3OGY4YTUzYjUwMjk6MDVlODA3ZDk0NDljNGE1MmFlMzM1YTQxOTlhMjMzYmI'
       }}
  }

  response() {
    console.log(this.opts)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.opts))
    return this._args[1];
  }

  getAccessToken(){
    const url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";

    fetch(url, {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(this.opts)
    })
   .then(function (data) {
      console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Request failed', error);
    }); 
  }
  pausePlayback(){
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = 
    http.open("POST", url);
    http.send();
    alert(http.responseText);
  }
}
```

This is the full error. I get when I try to make the post request.

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", redirected: false, status: 415, ok: false, …}
type: "cors"
url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
redirected: false
status: 415
ok: false
statusText: ""
headers: Headers
__proto__: Headers
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
__proto__: Response
```

Comment: I assume you looked up what 415 means, in the spotify API documentation for the specific API endpoint you're using? What did it say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" and encoded my json body and it's all working now

Comment: I also had a few errors with CORS so I had to create a proxy api to communicate with the spotify api.

Answer (score 1):

415 suggests you are sending data with the incorrect `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 0):

`415 - Unsupported Media` is a client error which indicates that the server has refused to accept the request because the request payload is of an unsupported format.

The possible error could be due to the wrong `Content-Type` or `Content-Encoding`. Your request seem to be of `JSON` format. Try setting the `Content-Type` to `application-json` (if not already) and see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I think my headers are messed up. I'll try that now.